# sparse_to_dense requires indices to be lexicographically sorted in 0.7

Tags: tensorflow

There was a change in behavior between versions 0.7 and 0.6 in `sparse_to_dense` that now requires the indices to be lexicographically sorted. This is a somewhat onerous requirement for some of my uses because the way I generate the indices is matched to the way I generate the elements (third arg of `sparse_to_dense`) and sorting both is a bit of a hassle. I see that the `validate_indices` option can be set to `False` to ignore this. Is it safe to do so? Why the requirement in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the current implementation for [`tensorflow::sparse::SparseTensor::ToDense<T>()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/875a67f3d298ab7f7438a3004e4597c71d92b529/tensorflow/core/util/sparse/sparse_tensor.h#L310), it seems that the conversion does not depend on the order of indices. Therefore, you can run [`tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_indices, ..., validate_indices=False)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_to_dense) on unsorted `sparse_indices`. A consistent result will be produced as long as there are no duplicate indices (otherwise it looks like the current implementation is last writer wins, but that is not guaranteed in the API).

It looks like the requirement for lexicographically sorted indices arises from a desire to check that there are no duplicates in `sparse_indices`. You can check the order property *and* absence of duplicates with a simple scan over the indices tensor (only considering rows `i` and `i - 1`), whereas checking for duplicates in an order independent fashion is more expensive. Since there's limited upside to the more conservative check, and a potentially large performance downside, we chose not to implement it, but the documentation could be clearer on this point!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This works for my purposes. It would be great if the spec is updated to reflect the fact that with `validate_indices=False` it is ok to pass in nonredundant unsorted indices, as I will rely on this behavior and it will be a problem if it changes without warning.